In Notebook, what argument do I need to provide in the main method in java which contains the argument "String args[]"
// class definition - to simulate and create a Dice class and execute its methods
class Dice
{
    // properties
    int dotCount = 1; // initializing the dice to show side with 1 dot for testing 

    // show the number of dots that the dice is showing
    void showDots(){
        System.out.println("Number of dots: " + dotCount);        
    }

    // simulate rolling of dice
    void rollDice(){
        dotCount = 5; // value assigned to simulate roll dice. TODO Use Random later
        System.out.println("Dice Rolled");
    }
    
    public static void main (){
        Dice obj = new Dice();
        obj.showDots();
        obj.rollDice();
        obj.showDots();        
    }
}

In Notebook, when the following code is executed in the next cell:
Dice.main();
The output is as expected:

Number of dots: 1
Dice Rolled
Number of dots: 5

However, when I replace the line:
public static void main ()
with
public static void main (String args[])
I get the following error:

|   Dice.main();
cannot find symbol
  symbol:   variable Dice

What argument do I have to provide in the Dice.main() in order for it to run in the second case? I tried Dice.main({""}), it didn't work.
